Python0CC: Edges created from Intersection of surfaces
So I am trying to access the edges that are obtained when I use the boolean operation Section on surfaces. My goal is to use those intersection edges to create a wire profile which I will then extrude to create another surface. Can anyone help with a code in PythonOCC?
Thanks
Below is a code I worked on. The first one create the sections which works fine but the second one which is supposed to create the edges keeps on failing
def section():
    sections = []
    for i in range(len(theBodies)):
        # Computes Torus/Sphere section
        section_shp = BRepAlgoAPI_Section(shp, theBodies[i], False)
        section_shp.ComputePCurveOn1(True)
        section_shp.Approximation(True)
        section_shp.Build()
        sections.append(section_shp)


    #display.EraseAll()
    #display.DisplayShape(shp)
    #for section_ in sections:
        #display.DisplayShape(section_.Shape())
    #display.FitAll()
    return sections

def sect_edges():
    # Obtaining the intersecting edges
    sectioning = section()
    for i in range(len(sectioning)):
        intersect_edges = sectioning[i].SectionEdges()
        for intersect_edge in intersect_edges:
            intersect_edge = TopoDS_Edge(intersect_edge)
            anAisEdge = AIS_Shape(intersect_edge)
            display.Context.Display(anAisEdge,True)


